# Frame Motion exit animation not working with Next.JS

Tags: javascript, animation, next.js, transition, framer-motion

I'm studying Next.JS and Framer Motion to improve my skills. So, I'm trying to make a fade-in/fade-out page transition, but can't get it to work properly, and can't figure out why.

The fade-in animation works fine, but, when I click (change current page), the fade-out isn't showing...

Here's my code:

/shared/layout.js

```js
export default function Layout({ children }){
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
            </Head>
            <Header />
            <main>
                <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
                    { children }
                </AnimatePresence>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

/pages/_app.js

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

/pages/index.js

```js
export default function Home(){
  return (
    <motion.div id="home" initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ opacity: 0 }} transition={{ duration: .5 }}>
      <Head>
        <title>Home</title>
      </Head>
      
      // Bla bla bla goes here
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

/pages/about.js

```js
export default function About(){
  return (
    <motion.div id="about" initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ opacity: 0 }} transition={{ duration: .5 }}>
      <Head>
        <title>About</title>
      </Head>
      
      // Bla bla bla goes here
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

/pages/contact.js

```js
export default function Contact(){
  return (
    <motion.div id="home" initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ opacity: 0 }} transition={{ duration: .5 }}>
      <Head>
        <title>Contact</title>
      </Head>
      
      // Bla bla bla goes here
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

While searching, I've found a lot of people saying "currently, exit animation won't work if you don't add an initial state", but I'm using initial prop on all motion.div components, and my AnimatePresence is in the right place (I think), as the parent for all motion.div components.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the same by using following code in the _app

```
<motion.div
  initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
  animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
  exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
  key={router.asPath}
  transition={{
    duration: 0.3,
    ease: 'easeInOut',
    type: 'tween',
  }}
>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</motion.div>
```

Comment: It's a good idea... But, I've tried here your approach and didn't worked for me. The fade-in animation runs once page load, and nothing happens when trying to navigate... I want a fade-in/fade-out transition between pages rs... Sorry

Comment: You must be implementing it in a wrong way. Maybe if you add more code I'll be able to help you

Comment: I just uploaded my code to my GitHub... Can you check it and help me? [NextJS Project](https://github.com/RBFraphael/cedge-website-nextjs) Thanks!!

Comment: Update the code of your question to the latest version(what you have tried). And then try to delete AnimatePresence and just use the code that I've posted instead

Answer (score 1):

I did almost the same and I had the same issue.
I resolved it by doing this in  `/pages/_app.js` :

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  return (
      <Layout>
        <Component key={router.pathname} {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

So I just added a key for the `Component` using the router given by Nextjs.